# Breeze.js used in production anywhere?

Tags: breeze

I haven't seen recent updates to the Breeze website (except for the Copyright), and I can't find any evidence that this is actually used in a production website. Does anyone know if this is a viable production ready product, or is this just a teaching tool?

Comment: I agree with @TravisSchettler.  We use it heavily in angular apps for our organization.  Breeze.js is an integral part of our stack

Comment: Great! I appreciate the feedback. We like Breeze, and want to use it. This feedback really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is production-ready and I have deployed a few websites to production that use breeze.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it Production.

In breeze site at bottom they have written that "free & open source".